# Design approach for feeds

Tags: algorithm

We have feeds running between external systems and our system that brings in investment data. These feeds run every 15 minutes. Every time feeds run, we update a LastRun timestamp column that indicates feed ran successfully. To force a feed to run, we set that feed's LastRun timestamp to NULL.

I am working on some new workflow that will let my users create investments in our own system. Once investment is created in the original external system, feed will get that in, and I will link that investment to the one I created. While linking, I will force-run the feeds related to investments to get other investment-related data.

Issue I am having is, what if feed is already running when I set the LastRun timestamp to null? It will not know that linking has happened, and it will simply update the LastRun timestamp and be on its way. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do one thing that make a table that will keep id,status and dt_created where you keep the new investment done to your system and set the status flag to **no**. now when you run the feed check the status flag if it is no then run the feed and after running update it to **yes** 
hope this can solve your problem

Comment: This would involve a change in all my feeds - and there are around 20 of them - to read and update the Status flag.

Comment: then just do one thing make a wrapper function which will actually call your feed and on that wrapper function you check the status and will determined if the run of your feed i think that will involve less change in your feed.

Comment: was my previous solution helpful??? please let me know if i can help you with something more...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I built upon your flag approach and got a different, nicer approach that requires no change in my feeds.